# extra commas in csv causing problems

Tags: r

I have a very large csv files that has the following structure

```
123, NAME1, EMAIL1@ADDRESS.COM
111, NAME2, EMAIL2@ADRESS.ME
```

The problem is that some names have a comma, something like

```
699, FIRST M. LAST, Jr., EMAIL4@ADDRESS.GOV
```

Is there a way to solve this? The original csv has aprox 80k entries, so doing it by hand is not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: How were the CSV files generated? If possible, you can try to reexport them specifying that strings should be quoted.

Comment: I'm trying to get the people to reexport the file like that, but it could take time. I was hoping for some R magic to solve the problem.

Comment: Without some data to play with I can't turn that into an answer, but I think that possibly `library( "stringr" )` and in that, `str_split_fixed()` could lead to a result. Is it always the same string, or are there other culprits (", Esq.,") or more than one additional comma?

Comment: If the data format is regular, perhaps a regular expression wiz will be able to suggest something. For instance, in this example data, you have a pattern of numbers for one variable, characters for the second, and an email address for the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an R solution using a regular expression:

```
file <- textConnection("123, NAME1, EMAIL1@ADDRESS.COM
111, NAME2, EMAIL2@ADRESS.ME
699, FIRST M. LAST, Jr., EMAIL4@ADDRESS.GOV")

lines   <- readLines(file)
pattern <- "^(\\d+), (.*), \\b(.*)$"
matches <- regexec(pattern, lines)

bad.rows <- which(sapply(matches, length) == 1L)
if (length(bad.rows) > 0L) stop(paste("bad row: ", lines[bad.rows]))

data <- regmatches(lines, matches)
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), ncol = 4L, byrow = TRUE)[, -1L])

#    V1                 V2                 V3
# 1 123              NAME1 EMAIL1@ADDRESS.COM
# 2 111              NAME2   EMAIL2@ADRESS.ME
# 3 699 FIRST M. LAST, Jr. EMAIL4@ADDRESS.GOV
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2 steps , you can do this for example:

```
## read using `fill=TRUE`
dat <- read.table(text='
123, NAME1, EMAIL1@ADDRESS.COM
111, NAME2, EMAIL2@ADRESS.ME
699, FIRST M. LAST, Jr., EMAIL4@ADDRESS.GOV',sep=',',
                  fill=TRUE,
                  header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
## concatenate names when they contain a comma
dat$V3 <- ifelse(nchar(dat$V4)>0,paste(dat$V3,dat$V4,sep=','),dat$V3)
dat[,-4]
   V1             V2                       V3
1 123          NAME1       EMAIL1@ADDRESS.COM
2 111          NAME2         EMAIL2@ADRESS.ME
3 699  FIRST M. LAST  Jr., EMAIL4@ADDRESS.GOV
```

Comment: Your solution is not working with the real data. When I read the table I only get 4 columns. I think this is because the first extra comma is in like 74 of the csv file. :_(

Comment: what do you mean by " is in like 74 of the csv file" ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple python script to convert my data

```
import sys

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    x = line.split(',')
    x = [token.strip() for token in x]
    x = [x[0], '"%s"' % (",".join(x[1:-1])), x[-1]]
    print ";".join(x)
```

To run it

```
python conv.py input.txt > output.txt
```

After that, I can read it in R without a problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a commonly asked question, and one of the better answers is to use `scan` or `readLines` to load the whole mess into `R` and then make use of `gsub` or other regex tools to split the lines into the desired elements.

EDIT:  see flodel's answer for details on this approach