# R import dirty csv with readLines use regular expressions to convert to dataframe

Tags: regex, r, csv

I'm trying to use Flodel's answer here ([extra commas in csv causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831042/extra-commas-in-csv-causing-problems)) in order to import some messy CSV data, but I'm having trouble implementing the solution.

When I have more columns than three, I don't know how to get the text and extra comma into my desired column. I'm pretty sure the problem is in my pattern; I just don't know how to fix it.

```
file <- textConnection("123, hi, NAME1, EMAIL1@ADDRESS.COM
111, hi, NAME2, EMAIL2@ADRESS.ME
699, hi, FIRST M. LAST, Jr., EMAIL4@ADDRESS.GOV")

lines   <- readLines(file)
pattern <- "^(\\d+), (.*), (.*), \\b(.*)$"
matches <- regexec(pattern, lines)

bad.rows <- which(sapply(matches, length) == 1L)
if (length(bad.rows) > 0L) stop(paste("bad row: ", lines[bad.rows]))

data <- regmatches(lines, matches)
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), ncol = 5L, byrow = TRUE)[, -1L])
```

which gives me

```
V1                V2    V3                 V4
123                hi NAME1 EMAIL1@ADDRESS.COM
111                hi NAME2   EMAIL2@ADRESS.ME
699 hi, FIRST M. LAST   Jr. EMAIL4@ADDRESS.GOV
```

I'd like to see:

```
V1                V2    V3                             V4
123                hi NAME1              EMAIL1@ADDRESS.COM
111                hi NAME2                EMAIL2@ADRESS.ME
699                hi FIRST M. LAST, Jr. EMAIL4@ADDRESS.GOV
```

Comment: If it's explicitly two-character suffixes with a period causing the issue, you can do it all in one with `as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(lines, ', (?!..\\., )', perl = TRUE)), ncol = 4L, byrow = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're more explicit with what you want to match on, you might get better results. If column two will always only have a single string that does not include a comma, you can use:

```
pattern <- "^(\\d+), ([^,]+), (.*), \\b(.*)$"
```

In my experience, making your regular expression as explicit as you can first and then generalizing when that stops working is the best approach. e.g. if the second string is always `hi` include that in your regex.

```
pattern <- "^(\\d+), (hi), (.*), \\b(.*)$"
```